# (kubernetes/GKE) How do I route traffic in istio based on client IP address?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, servicemesh

I am using GKE, with it's own set of istio mesh enabled. I do have a gateway and a virtual service, which is routing traffic just fine. But I wanted to direct traffic to diffrent paths based on source IPs.
I do realise that we could use match / headers in virtual service as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62207744/service-mesh-using-istio-to-route-tcp-traffic-based-on-client-ip-in-virtual-ser), as below:

```
  - match:
- headers:
    x-forwarded-for:
      exact: 123.123.123.123
```

But it doesnt seem to work for me. Please suggest, thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, there are several things that could make this difficult. First if you are using a loadbalancer, it could be overwriting source ip. Second it depends on your gateway configuration and protocol that is being used.  Can you provide more details how requests reach your cluster? Also could you provide yaml manifests of your gateway, virtualservice, destinationrules, service and deployment?

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for the quick response, I will check the loadbalancer settings and other criteria.

Comment: According to this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647973/istio-authorization-policy-not-applying-on-child-gateway/63682724#63682724), you will also need to set `externalTrafficPolicy` to `local`.